# cxf LOGGING of soap messages - reduce payload - delete binaryStreamList WildFly

Tags: apache, logging, soap, cxf, wildfly-10

Actually i have a problem with Webservice-Framework Apache CXF Integration/Intstalling in WildFly v.10  - org.apache.cxf.

Every SOAP message is logged in a special file soap.log. This is configured in standalone.xml of JBoss. The Problem is that the logged SOAP messages contains <-binaryStreamList><-bytes>...<-bytes> - Base64 Data - which is too much (unuseful and unreadble information). How can i disable the logging of Base64 crypted data in the <-binaryStreamList> section of logged SOAP messages?

EXAMPLE OF logged SOAP Message:

Payload: <-soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><-soap:Body><-raum>TEST<-/raum><-clientU 
ser><-System><-/clientUser><-nummer>99999<-/nummer><-kNumber>9111111<-/kNumber><-nameOfFile>test.pdf<-/nameOfFile>

<-binaryStreamList>

<-bytes>JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9TdWJ0e 
XBlL1R5cGUxL1R5cGUvRm9udC9CYXNlRm9udC9IZWx2ZXRpY2EvRW5jb2RpbmcvV2luQW5zaUVuY29kaW5nPj4KZW5kb2JqCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwvTW9kRGF0ZShEOjIwMTcwNzA1MTM1MDM5KzAyJzAwJykvQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlKEQ6 
MjAxNzA3MDUxMzUwMzkrMDInMDAnKS9Qcm9kdWNlcihpVGV4dK4gNS41LjYgqTIwMDAtMjAxNSBpVGV4dCBHcm91cCBOViBcKEFHUEwtdmVyc2lvblwpOyBtb2RpZmllZCB1c2luZyBpVGV4dK.....<-bytes>

Comment: Base64 is not encryption, it is a simple encoding.